# What does the phrase "If you surrendered to the air, you could ride it" mean?

Tags: toni-morrison, song-of-solomon-morrison

I find the final passage of Toni Morrison's *Song of Solomon* to be a bit confusing.

> As fleet and bright as a lodestar, he wheeled towards Guitar and it did not matter which one of them would give up his ghost in the killing arms of his brother. For now he knew what Shalimar knew: If you surrendered to the air, you could *ride* it.

I've thought about it, but I'm not quite sure why it's important to "surrender to the air"? How does that lead to the ability to "ride" the air? Any insight into the meaning of "If you surrendered to the air, you could *ride* it" would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Throughout the book, Solomon loses things.  They start small and grow larger.  He learns that he can “fly,” but it’s going to cost him.  Everything.  It symbolizes his losing all the things of this world that weigh him down so that he is light as a feather and can truly be free.

Comment: This seems like the start of a good interpretation, but can you provide a bit more detail? What things does Solomon lose? How does he learn that he can fly? How is it going to cost him? Can you quote passages from the text supporting this interpretation?

Answer (score -1):

In the Taoist book of Lieh-Tzu, Lieh-Tzu suggest that it’s possible to ride the wind. He achieved this state late in his life. His bones no longer weighed him down, he was as light as a feather. He could not tell if he was riding the wind or the wind was riding him. It’s not to be taken literally, but metaphysically. It’s a mental state one can achieve when you let go of your earthly desires and let your own will become one with the will of the universe. It’s having without possessing, doing without acting. Everyone knows that flying is possible with wings but no one seems understand flying without wings.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. This is a good connection to make, but can you provide any evidence that Morrison had Lieh-Tsu in mind when she wrote these lines? Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).